# Remote port forwarding in Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, portforwarding

I tried translate command
`ssh -R 80:localhost:8080 nokey@localhost.run` (It works as it should, problem not in server)
to Paramiko with help of https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/rforward.py

My code:

```
import paramiko
from rforward import reverse_forward_tunnel
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(username="nokey", hostname="localhost.run")
transport = ssh.get_transport()
reverse_forward_tunnel(8080, "localhost.run", 80, transport)
```

But it fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):    ...
raise SSHException("TCP forwarding request denied")  paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: TCP forwarding request denied
```

Help pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-R 80:localhost:8080
```

That forwards remote port `80` to local `localhost:8080`.

That imo maps to `reverse_forward_tunnel` as

```
reverse_forward_tunnel(80, "localhost", 8080, transport)
```

Basically, the same order of arguments (and `localhost`, not `localhost.run`).